# Having trouble logging in to IMAP account in Python3.61

Tags: python

I am developing a Python script in version 3.61 to connect to an Imap server and select all email messages older than a certain date. I imported the imapclient module and then provided the following in the IDLE shell:

```
HOST = 'imap.comcast.net'
USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'topsecret'
ssl = False
server = IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=ssl)
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```

I received the following errors after using the login option:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1011, in _command_complete
typ, data = self._get_tagged_response(tag)
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1123, in 
_get_tagged_response
self._check_bye()
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 926, in _check_bye
raise self.abort(bye[-1].decode(self._encoding, 'replace'))
imaplib.IMAP4.abort: Zimbra IMAP server terminating connection

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", 
line 
215, in login
unpack=True,
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", 
line 
1180, in _command_and_check
typ, data = meth(*args)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 588, in login
typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1188, in _simple_command
return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\imaplib.py", line 1013, in _command_complete
raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
imaplib.IMAP4.abort: command: LOGIN => Zimbra IMAP server terminating 
connection
```

The docs indicate to me that this should be sufficient to make the connection but it is not clear why the connection is terminated after attempting the login.

Any help provided would be most welcome.

Comment: Does it change anything if you add a `server.starttls()` before `server.login()`? If that doesn't help: Test against a different IMAP server.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I am just now getting the time to use your recommendations. I added the server.starttls() option and I received a similar message when I passed the server.login() option.  Also I did test the script against a different IMAP server but the connection was not made because the server did not respond in sufficient time. But I did not find a reason why the server object does not provide sufficient parameters for connection. Am I thinking about this correctly?